# Self-referential data type with single constructor cannot be `Show`n

Tags: haskell, types, sml, self-reference

This is from *The Little MLer*. I have [this](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=fqHeFu_K_HoC&q=a%20very%20long%20sequence#v=snippet&q=a%20very%20long%20sequence&f=false)

```
data Chain = Link Int (Int -> Chain)
```

and this

```
ints :: Int -> Chain
ints n = Link (n+1) ints
```

I'm rather confused as to what exactly is happening here. It seems like an endless recursion of itself where `ints`on the left-hand side is just repeating the whole `ints` endlessly. The book is saying

> [...] we may think of `ints` as a very long sequence of `ints`. We go from one
> element in this sequence to the next by applying the second component
> of `ints n` to the first.

I'm not sure how it does this. But then this produces an error

```
> ints 0
* No instance for (Show Chain) arising from a use of `print'
:     * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

An attempt to tack on `deriving Show` won't fly

```
data Chain = Link Int (Int -> Chain) deriving Show
No instance for (Show (Int -> Chain))
        arising from the second field of `Link' (type `Int -> Chain')
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    * When deriving the instance for (Show Chain)
```

Not sure what is going on or how to proceed.  Any similar examples would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

Here's the SML code

```
datatype chain = Link of (int * (int -> chain))
fun ints (n) = Link (n+1, ints)
> ints(0)
val it = Link (1,fn) : chain
```

Not totally sure, but that `fn` is the SML way of doing anonymous, i.e. `fn` is their `\`. This might just be a coincidence.

So what's SML got that Haskell can't handle? Is this something to do with Haskell being pure and SML is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going on is this:

```hs
current :: Chain -> Int
current (Link i _) = i

next :: Chain -> Chain
next (Link i g) = g i
```

just as the quote is saying. Your `ints` is a function, so nothing infinite is going on here, just a delayed possibility of function application to get the *next* `Link` in a chain so the next `Int` can be found as *its* `current` element.

As for the printing,

```hs
printLink :: Link -> String
printLink (Link i _) = "{Link of " ++ show i ++ " }"
```

is one possible definition. There's nothing informative we can say about the function so we will just have to ignore it.

Example interaction:

```
ch1 = ints 0
i1 = current ch1  -- 1
ch2 = next ch1  
i2 = current ch2  -- 2
```

etc.

Next we can define `takeN :: Int -> Chain -> [Int]` so that `takeN 5 ch1`  returns the list of five `Int`s from the chain `ch1`, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

SML is strict, it can't have infinite lists like Haskell can. So instead, SML represents the "next" computation by a function, which *you* have to invoke explicitly.

Since Haskell is lazy, we cold also just define `chainToList :: Chain -> [Int]` to convert a chain to an infinite list of entries in it, and then use the standard function `take` on that.

In your new SML example, "`fn`" is just an indicator that there's *a* function there, *some* function. In your case it's the function `ints` but the run-time system apparently doesn't know that. This probably means that *any* function will get printed as "`fn`" in SML as your example shows.

But you don't need to print it to use it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how this ties in? Not following you very well.

Comment: @147pm I've edited the answer. does it address your concerns better now?

Comment: See my self-answer. This was all a case of nerves, as it turns out. Although I think the concept of `Chain` is cool, which is why I leave this beginner's panic up.

Comment: "leave this beginner's panic up" I don't understand. do you have an option to delete your question? ---- so is my answer clear now? do you see now how `next` is doing what you describe in your answer, calling the stored function with the current item, to get the next link?

Comment: Yes, and I thank you. I'm assuming this whole topic was created by the authors to show how taking and producing a function can be a bit beyond run-of-the-mill.

Answer (score 7):

In general there is no good way to `Show` a function, so Haskell will not make an instance of `Show` for you when a function is involved..

You could write one yourself:

```
instance Show Chain where
  show (Link n fn) = ...
```

But now you have to figure out how to show `fn:: Int->Chain`. In Haskell at least functions are atomic and opaque. You can't break them apart or inspect their contents, only apply them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of having not read ahead far enough in the text, as well as getting a false positive from one language (SML) but not the other. As it turns out, getting a `Chain` returning function like `ints` to do direct output is a misapplication. These `Chain` "generators" are only there as an intermediary for another function to "look up" what is where in such a `Chain` object, in TLMLer's examples, the next integer in the second part of the data constructor.

```
data Chain = Link Int (Int -> Chain)
```

So consider another `Chain` generator `fiveOrsevenInts`

```
mod5or7 n = if (evenDiv n 5) then True else (evenDiv n 7)
                where evenDiv a b = ((a `mod` b) == 0)

fiveOrsevenInts n = if (mod5or7 (n+1))
             then (Link (n+1) fiveOrsevenInts)
             else fiveOrsevenInts (n+1)
```

`fiveOrsevenInts` creates a `Chain` based on numbers divisible by 5 or 7. As I learned, the whole idea is getting a "read ahead" of the "chain." So if

```
fiveOrsevenInts (1) => Link 5 fiveOrsevenInts
```

the trick is to get `fiveOrsevenInts` (the `Int -> Chain` function) to act on the `5` to get the next `Int` in the chain. And as I mistakenly thought, we don't need to "see" the above direct resolution of `fiveOrsevenInts (1)` at all.

A general function to take desired position in the chain sequence and a chain-producing function like `fiveOrsevenInts` and give back the member for that position would be

```
chainItem n (Link i f) = if (n == 1)
                         then i
                         else chainItem (n-1) (f i)
```

Now if I want to see the first in a sequence of integers multiples of 5 or 7 it's just

```
chainItem 1 (fiveOrsevenInts 0)
5
chainItem 2  (fiveOrsevenInts 0)
7
chainItem 3  (fiveOrsevenInts 0)
10
...
chainItem 37  (fiveOrsevenInts 0)
119
```

where `fiveOrsevenInts 0` "seeds" the `Chain`. Later in the chapter this strategy is applied to finding a sequence of primes by building a prime `Chain` generator. All in all, I'm finding *The Little MLer* a fun way to learn its sibling Haskell. When I'm through I'll try to share my overall translation.

Comment: BTW the type is loose. nothing precludes you from mis-using a link, e.g. through `foobar (Link i g) = g 0`. so there is no chain in that datum; there is a chain only in the combination of that datum with some functions which are using it *correctly*. A tight data type wouldn't need that, e.g. `data IChain = ILink Int (() -> IChain)` and then `intsFrom n = ILink n (\() -> intsFrom (n+1))`. now you simply can't mis-apply the stored function. the `n+1` is hidden, can't be gotten to freely, but only through controlled means provided by the type. this is a.k.a "encapsulation" in OOP parlance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying here. I don't understand what's meant by "tight" data type. I also don't understand your application of the Unit `()` in `data IChain = ILink Int (() -> IChain)` or the `intsFrom n = ILink n (\() -> intsFrom (n+1))`.

Comment: My `fiveOrsevenInt` will "move up the chain" until `chainItem` tells it to stop. Creating a lazy version of all this would rely on `fiveOrsevenInt` being an infinite data structure, e.g., the chain equivalent of the infinite list `[1..]`. I'll look around for such a beast.

Comment: just as I said, the `Chain` datatype allows semantically erroneous definitions like `foobar`, so, "loose" -- allows us to do many things besides its _intended_ use (which is `current` and `next`). but `g = (\() -> intsFrom (n+1))` is a closure, it holds onto its own `n` inside, to be used in the next step calculation, so an `IChain` value can't be misused -- no `ifoobar` is possible. the only thing we can do with `g` is to call `g ()`. _we_ don't give it its argument to work on, the value `n` is already inside. hence "tight" -- the type does not allow us any "freedoms", the only use possible -

Comment: the type does not allow us any "freedoms", the only use possible *is* its *intended* use. it's like trying hard to write correct programs and avoiding making errors (like defining `foobar`) vs. having programs which are *correct by construction.* ---- we only need such type `() -> Chain` in strict languages. In Haskell we can just have `data LChain = LLink Int LChain`, and then `IntsLFrom n = LLink n (intsLFrom (n+1))`.

Comment: you can just try those snippets, and try defining functions like `takeNElements` for each of them. if you run into problems you can always post a new question. :)

Comment: another thing is, the type is only loose because it is concrete (has `Int`s in it). If it were parametric, `data PChain a = PLink a (a -> PChain a)`, then it would be tight: we can't define `pfoobar` now, as we can't get some `a` out of thin air whatever the `a` type is. because we don't know anything about it (unlike `Int`). so `pcurrent` and `pnext` are the only two functions we can define for this datatype (except for nonsensical definitions causing an error intentionally, like `pfoobar _ = error "ooh oh"` or `pfoobar _ = undefined`).

Comment: @ Will Ness: Could you get me started with `IChain`? I've got `iCurrent (ILink i _) = i` which works, but `iNext (ILink i g) = g i` gives an error `Couldn't match expected type () with actual type Int`. I guess I'm not understanding how the `(Int -> Chain)` and the `(() -> IChain)` are actually working in the type defs.

Comment: right. it's `() -> IChain`, so the type of the argument it expects is `()`. there's only one value of that type, also written as `()`, but it's a value, not a type. so the only thing we *can* do is `iNext (ILink _ g) = g ()`.

Comment: Thanks again. I had to change `intsFrom n = ILink n (\() -> intsFrom (n+1))` to `intsFrom (n+1) = ILink n (\() -> intsFrom (n+1))` to have it work. And I changed everything so far over to `IList` successfully, but I'm just not clear on how or why `iNext (ILink _ g) = g ()` is working. I sort of get how it's working as a closure (instead of generating the "next in chain" from `g i`), i.e., `INext` somehow hands over the `Int` value out of that closure, but how? `g ()` is unpacking the closure's `n+1` and giving that back as the answer mystifies me. Again, `()` is foreign to me.

Comment: `current (intsFrom 1)` should be `1`, not `0`. so you shouldn't have changed that. "closure" is a function which remembers its free variables' values. the `n` in `\ () -> intsFrom (n+1)` is free. it refers to the `n` in the enclosing context, `intsFrom n = ...`. you should probably  read some more introductory material like tutorial like Learn You a Haskell, for all that. cheers.

Comment: Ach, I have five more years of "introductory material" ahead of me. Haskell isn't a walk in the park.

Comment: 'closure' is much more pertinent a concept in the Lisp world, where mutation (changing a binding's  variable's value) comes into play. in Haskell it is even easier, it's just about lexical scope, and referencing the variable which is in plain sight. I see you have participated in lisp tags. Haskell is just a Lisp with nicer syntax and without mutation -- neither variables can change nor the data they point to, only modified copies can be made from them to be referred to by new variables. as to the `()`, it's just one special value, like `NIL` is a special symbol. (or `T`).